# Convert rdf to xml with python

Tags: python, rdf

Hi I have this RDF Input and I want make it to xml style with python , now how can I do?

```
@prefix Person: <http://example.org/> .

Person:Sophie Person:gender "women" ;
    Person:likes Person:Peter .

Person:Frank Person:bornIn "1949" ;
    Person:gender "Men" ;
    Person:married Person:Susie .

Person:Peter Person:father Person:Frank ;
    Person:gender "Men" ;
    Person:likes Person:Sandra ;
    Person:mother Person:Susie .

Person:Sandra Person:bornIn "1980" ;
    Person:gender "women" .

Person:Susie Person:bornIn "1956" ;
    Person:gender "women" .
```

Comment: use [rdflib](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and write as `RDF/XML` - done. Indeed, this RDF/XML will contain all the RDF specific metadata.

Comment: added to and this happend :  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugin.py", line 103, in get
    p = _plugins[(name, kind)]
KeyError: ('RDF/XML', <class 'rdflib.serializer.Serializer'>)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
rdflib.plugin.PluginException: No plugin registered for (RDF/XML, <class 'rdflib.serializer.Serializer'>) @UninformedUser

Comment: edit my tagToXml.write(graph.serialize(format='turtle').decode('utf-8')) to tagToXml.write(graph.serialize(format='RDF/XML').decode('utf-8')) make runtime error @UninformedUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the `rdflib` package and use it to convert between the RDF formats.  In your case it looks like the data is stored in the "notation3" syntax.  To parse this you need to specify the format when reading the graph as `'n3'`.

I am using `StringIO` in place of actual files below, but the concept is the same.

```
import rdflib
from io import StringIO, BytesIO

str_in = StringIO('''@prefix Person: <http://example.org/> .

Person:Sophie Person:gender "women" ;
    Person:likes Person:Peter .

Person:Frank Person:bornIn "1949" ;
    Person:gender "Men" ;
    Person:married Person:Susie .

Person:Peter Person:father Person:Frank ;
    Person:gender "Men" ;
    Person:likes Person:Sandra ;
    Person:mother Person:Susie .

Person:Sandra Person:bornIn "1980" ;
    Person:gender "women" .

Person:Susie Person:bornIn "1956" ;
    Person:gender "women" .'''
)

g = rdflib.Graph()
g.parse(str_in, format='n3')
```

At this point the data is loaded into the graph.  If you want write it out to a new format, such as XML, you can do so via the following.  To write to a file, just put in a file path as the first argument of `g.serialize()`.

```
g.serialize('path/to/file.xml', format='pretty-xml')

with open('path/to/file.xml') as fp:
    print(fp.read())
# prints:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:Person="http://example.org/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/Sophie">
    <Person:likes>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/Peter">
        <Person:gender>Men</Person:gender>
        <Person:likes rdf:resource="http://example.org/Sandra"/>
        <Person:father rdf:resource="http://example.org/Frank"/>
        <Person:mother rdf:resource="http://example.org/Susie"/>
      </rdf:Description>
    </Person:likes>
    <Person:gender>women</Person:gender>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/Susie">
    <Person:gender>women</Person:gender>
    <Person:bornIn>1956</Person:bornIn>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/Frank">
    <Person:married rdf:resource="http://example.org/Susie"/>
    <Person:bornIn>1949</Person:bornIn>
    <Person:gender>Men</Person:gender>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/Sandra">
    <Person:bornIn>1980</Person:bornIn>
    <Person:gender>women</Person:gender>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```